# Modify behavior of core Mercurial commands using extensions?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to modify the behavior of a core Mercurial command (e.g. `hg commit` or `hg status`) by creating an extension?

For example, would it be possible to modify `hg commit` to ask the user to enter an issue tracking ID?

I understand that hook scripts could be used, but such scripts are not distributed via `hg pull` and need to be configured for every repository used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can put a hook script in the user's hgrc to make it apply across all repositories.  Also, you could have the hook file be in a Mercurial repo...

Comment: @Borealid That may be true, but I am still interested to know the answer to my question.  There are other features I have considered adding for a corporate environment that would be much easier if extensions can modify core commands.  Unfortunately, there is not much documentation for the Mercurial API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Answering my own question*

The Mercurial API provides the [`extensions.wrapcommand(table, command, wrapper)`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/hg/hg/file/ce066f8aa0b2/mercurial/extensions.py#l106) method which seems to provide the desired feature.

From the source code:

> Wrap the command named `command' in
>   table.
>
> Replace command in the command table
>   with wrapper. The wrapped command will
>   be inserted into the command table
>   specified by the table argument. The
>   wrapper will be called like
>   wrapper(orig, *args, **kwargs) where
>   orig is the original (wrapped)
>   function, and *args, **kwargs are the
>   arguments passed to it.

A couple examples:

- The [`prompt`](http://bitbucket.org/sjl/hg-prompt/src/48b02f459ac0/prompt.py) extension by Steve Losh
- The [`nobranch`](https://me-demo.kilnhg.com/Tools/Downloads/Extensions/nobranch.py) extension from Fog Creek

Comment: Beware when wrapping commands not to alter the output.  Eclipse and other environments use the command line output for their integration and will choke if it varies.

Answer (score 2):

Just to note: both extensions and hooks have exactly the same mass-deployment limitations.  In both cases you have to induce your internal users to download a piece of software, be it a hook or an extension, and then to enable it in either the hgrc in their homedir or within the repo.

For both hooks and extensions you can distribute the software using any mechanism and can enable them globally in /etc/mercurial/hgrc

Extensions have some advantages over hooks as to how deep they can dig in the mercurial internals, but deployment is identical.